# Internet Explorer is not loading css of ONE Html file

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am building a website and almost everything is fine. On Internet Explorer there is exactly one Html file, that isn't displayed properly. It seems the css files are not loaded. The clue is: I copy and pasted the content of another html file from my website to this ominous file and it didn't work either. At this point I've reached my limit and wanted to ask if someone has a solution for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/column.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>StellerToGo</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/icon-web.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logomenu">
                <div class="navlogo">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.PNG">
                </div>
                    <a class="topnav menubutton" href="#" onclick="showMenu()">
                        <div class="text navtext">Menü       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <div class="link">
                    <a class="topnav text navtext" href="Startseite.html">Startseite</a>
                </div>
                <div class="link">
                    <a class="topnav text navtext" href="Kontakt.html">Über uns</a>
                </div>
                <div class="link">
                    <a class="topnav nav-selected text navtext" href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="component">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="title">
                    <p>Impressum</p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <div class="subtitle">Angaben gem&auml;&szlig; &sect; 5 TMG</div><br>
                    Max Mustermann<br>
                    Musterstra&szlig;e 111<br>
                    Geb&auml;ude 44<br>
                    90210 Musterstadt<br><br>
                    <div class="subtitle">Kontakt</div><br>
                    Telefon: +49 (0) 123 44 55 66<br>
                    Telefax: +49 (0) 123 44 55 99<br>
                    E-Mail: mustermann@musterfirma.de<br><br>
                    <div class="subtitle">Haftung f&uuml;r Inhalte</div><br>
                    Als Diensteanbieter sind wir gem&auml;&szlig; &sect; 7 Abs.1 TMG f&uuml;r eigene Inhalte auf diesen
                    Seiten nach den allgemeinen Gesetzen verantwortlich. Nach &sect;&sect; 8 bis 10 TMG sind wir als
                    Diensteanbieter jedoch nicht verpflichtet, &uuml;bermittelte oder gespeicherte fremde Informationen
                    zu &uuml;berwachen oder nach Umst&auml;nden zu forschen, die auf eine rechtswidrige T&auml;tigkeit
                    hinweisen.<br><br>Verpflichtungen zur Entfernung oder Sperrung der Nutzung von Informationen nach
                    den allgemeinen Gesetzen bleiben hiervon unber&uuml;hrt. Eine diesbez&uuml;gliche Haftung ist jedoch
                    erst ab dem Zeitpunkt der Kenntnis einer konkreten Rechtsverletzung m&ouml;glich. Bei Bekanntwerden
                    von entsprechenden Rechtsverletzungen werden wir diese Inhalte umgehend entfernen.<br><br>
                    <div class="subtitle">Haftung f&uuml;r Links</div><br>
                    Unser Angebot enth&auml;lt Links zu externen Websites Dritter, auf deren Inhalte wir keinen Einfluss
                    haben. Deshalb k&ouml;nnen wir f&uuml;r diese fremden Inhalte auch keine Gew&auml;hr
                    &uuml;bernehmen. F&uuml;r die Inhalte der verlinkten Seiten ist stets der jeweilige Anbieter oder
                    Betreiber der Seiten verantwortlich. Die verlinkten Seiten wurden zum Zeitpunkt der Verlinkung auf
                    m&ouml;gliche Rechtsverst&ouml;&szlig;e &uuml;berpr&uuml;ft. Rechtswidrige Inhalte waren zum
                    Zeitpunkt der Verlinkung nicht erkennbar.<br><br>Eine permanente inhaltliche Kontrolle der
                    verlinkten Seiten ist jedoch ohne konkrete Anhaltspunkte einer Rechtsverletzung nicht zumutbar. Bei
                    Bekanntwerden von Rechtsverletzungen werden wir derartige Links umgehend entfernen.<br><br>
                    <div class="subtitle">Urheberrecht</div><br>
                    Die durch die Seitenbetreiber erstellten Inhalte und Werke auf diesen Seiten unterliegen dem
                    deutschen Urheberrecht. Die Vervielf&auml;ltigung, Bearbeitung, Verbreitung und jede Art der
                    Verwertung au&szlig;erhalb der Grenzen des Urheberrechtes bed&uuml;rfen der schriftlichen Zustimmung
                    des jeweiligen Autors bzw. Erstellers. Downloads und Kopien dieser Seite sind nur f&uuml;r den
                    privaten, nicht kommerziellen Gebrauch gestattet.<br><br>Soweit die Inhalte auf dieser Seite nicht
                    vom Betreiber erstellt wurden, werden die Urheberrechte Dritter beachtet. Insbesondere werden
                    Inhalte Dritter als solche gekennzeichnet. Sollten Sie trotzdem auf eine Urheberrechtsverletzung
                    aufmerksam werden, bitten wir um einen entsprechenden Hinweis. Bei Bekanntwerden von
                    Rechtsverletzungen werden wir derartige Inhalte umgehend entfernen.<br><br>
                    <div class="subtitle">Quelle</div><br>
                    <a
                        href="https://www.e-recht24.de/impressum-generator.html">https://www.e-recht24.de/impressum-generator.html
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script/nav.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this is enough for you guys to figure something out. The content of the

tag should be alright as I copy and pasted it from an online generator, although it might still be a problem.(I don't know)
PS: This might not be the best html structure etc., so please just help me find a solution.

Comment: Odds are that you have added or omitted a `/` from the end of the URL to the HTML document and its broken your relative URLs. Check the develop tools Network tab to see what CSS URLs are actually being requested.

Comment: From your code, it seems that you are using external CSS style, please check whether the CSS external file exist or not in the current directory css folder. Whether the file path is correct? Besides, you could also use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the CSS files are load success. And use the F12 DOM Explorer tools to check whether the CSS style is overridden by other CSS style.

Comment: Ok, funny thing: I copied the content of the file and deleted the file. I created a file with an identical name and pasted the content of the file...It works. I don't know what to say...

Answer (score 0):

your html file are form other computers,you can try the following.

right click on the file.

click unlock(this file came from another computer and might be blocked)

from

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/883260/information-about-the-attachment-manager-in-microsoft-windows